# CloudFront-served CSS files not rendered

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

This is an odd issue, but I assume I've done something boneheaded somewhere along the line to end up with this current situation.

When trying to serve static files (images, css & js) from CloudFront, they don't seem to be rendering properly. For example, one of my stylesheets is available here: http://d21uvxjmc903qz.cloudfront.net/stylesheets/hf.4fabc9c719f8.css, but it doesn't seem to be "applied" to the DOM as I would expect. (For example, looking in developer tools in Chrome or Firefox in Firebug the relevant styles aren't applied to the `<header>` element.

Looking at the response headers, it looks like the `Content-Type` is set properly, so I'm pretty much out of ideas.

Any suggestions on where to look next?

Comment: Do you have a link to the site using it?

Comment: I assuming your including it in your HTML in [the right way](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssbeginner/applyingcss/).

Comment: Pretty sure I'm including it the right way, I'm using Django and the only change is the URL I'm referring to. (e.g., served off my local machine there are no problems, served off cloudfront it acts oddly.)

Comment: I don't have a link to the site using it unfortunately since it was just on my dev machine. I'll set up a test machine with it in the next few days. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

The problem is likely the wrong content-type in the S3 bucket. I had the same trouble, and changing the content-type fixed the issue. I changed the below from `text/plain` to `text/css` and then the styles rendered correctly.

[image]

Comment: I was experiencing the same issue and this fixed it for me.

Comment: Thank you TimDog!   Solved a 2hr+ issue for me.  You are the man!

Answer (score 2):

For me the link couldn't be http but had to be https://..
It worked for me when i modified this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="w3.css">
```

in the html file to this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/yourFolder/w3.css">`

hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a super old question but I found a solution that worked for me with the same problem: in the CloudFront console, I created a new 'invalidation' for `/*` which as I understand it forces requests for the static files to go to the origin instead of the CloudFront cache, and this fixed my css rendering issues as I had recently changed the location of css files in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Just had an issue with a CSS file served from cloudfront that we thought was not served correctly. The issue ended up being an unescaped single quote inside of a backgroud's url value.

```
background: url(//xxxxx.cloudfront.net/img/flags48/Cote%20d'Ivoire.png) no-repeat}
```

Once we replaced `'` with `%27`, the CSS issues were fixed.

```
background: url(//xxxxx.cloudfront.net/img/flags48/Cote%20d%27Ivoire.png) no-repeat}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Hugo to render my website. I found that I need to specify the HTTPS protocol in the value of `baseURL`, not just the path.

For example, in file `config.toml`:

```
baseURL = https://example.com
```

or on the command line,

```
hugo --baseURL https://example.com
```

A tip of the hat and +1 to @pascati, who led me to this Hugo solution.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem when using `s3cmd` to synchronise my local files with S3. The `s3cmd` client makes an assumption about the MIME type of the `.css` file and it returns with `Content-Type: text/plain`.

I fixed this using the following command flag with `s3cmd`:

`--no-mime-magic`

There are various other associated options - see https://s3tools.org/usage for more info.

You may need to invalidate your Cloudfront edge cache (and remove the file from S3 then sync again) before you can see this take effect.